# My collection will not go through all of my objects within

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a final project in my programming class in vb2010 and the collection I have created only goes through one of the objects in my `For Each... Next`. I have included the code where I add the objects to the collections and my For Each loop. Note: My code for adding to the collection may be a bit more complicated then it needs to be, but the idea was for it to be flexible and choose how many objects are added to the collection.

```vb
Private Sub basicCountCollect(ByVal basicCount As Short)
    Dim name As String = ""
    Dim PB As New PictureBox
    For ShipCount As Short = 1 To basicCount
        name = "basicShip" & ShipCount
        PB.Name = name
        basicShipCount.Add(PB)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BasicShipPictureBox(ByVal XPic As Short)
    'Display basic ship picture boxes
    For Each ship As PictureBox In basicShipCount
        ship.Location = New Point(XPic, 100) 'Location of the ship
        ship.Size = New Size(200, 200) 'Size of the ship
        ship.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile( _ 
            My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\basicShipImage.png") 'Load picture of the ship
        Me.Controls.Add(ship)
        XPic = XPic + 100
        MessageBox.Show(ship.Name) 'For debugging
    Next ship 
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried debugging it?  put the cursor on the For Each and press F9, then examine the variables as the loop runs - does it loop more than once?

Comment: I runs more than once, but only with one of the pictureboxes. It places that picturebox 5 times. I will see if there is something else though

Comment: your creation loop is wrong. you need `Dim PB As New PictureBox` *inside* the loop to make 5 different ones.  There is also no reason to actually create PictureBoxes there - all you need is a List(of String) to store the name

Comment: @Plutonix: Please post as an answer.